# Strategy to skip breakpoints based on stack trace

Tags: java, debugging, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

In Java, I am looking for a strategy to skip over a breakpoint conditional on the current thread stack trace.

For example, if `foo` calls `bar()` and if both `setup` and `showtime` call `foo()`, how could I design my code so that I could set a breakpoint in `bar` that is only triggered when it is called via `showtime()`?  What are some useful and simple strategies?  The code I am working with is test code so performance is not very important.

One thought I had was to set some kind of flag in the calling top-level methods that I could use in a conditional breakpoint, but I am interested in some other ideas particularly since this seems like a rather common use case to me.